# Three.js - WebGL Rendering Canvas remains black

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, html5-canvas, webgl

I recently started to work with WebGL by using the Threejs libary.

I tried to create some sort of image viewer, but I just can't seem to figure out how to do it right.
I want to display the image, a texture fetched from a HTML5-Canvas, on a PlaneGeometry object.

My code looks like this:

```
var RunWebGL = function(img, canvas){
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(img.width, img.height);
    document.body.append(renderer.domElement);

    //Init the Scene;
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    //Init the Camera;
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, img.width/img.height, 1, 1000); 
    scene.add(camera);

    //Init the texture from the image displayed in the canvas. Then use this image to create the Mesh used to give the created plane a texture;
    var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map : texture});
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(img.widht, img.height);

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    //Init the Geometry and the texture(material) and mesh it together;
    scene.add(mesh);

    renderer.setClearColor(0xEEEEEE);
    texture.needsUpdate = true;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
```

The HTML5-Canvas, which provides the image, displays it as expected.

Everything I get from the WebGL part tho is a black square everytime this code executes. On the search for an answer on this problem, I added "renderer.setClearColor();" - Which hasn't changed anything, execpt that I'm now getting a smooth grey instead of a dead black square.

I'm getting no Errors/Warnings/Whatsoever.

The img-object that is passed into my RunWebGL function is a standard JavaScript Image object.

If I could use this image as a texture instead of the canvas, I would be really happy. But an answer using the Canvas, or even a hint could help to decrease my struggle.

//Edit: I have created a JS-Fiddle that shows my problem. Here's the link: https://jsfiddle.net/a5ufknLu/2/

Cheers and thanks in advance,

Michael

Comment: Looks like your `camera` locates in position of `(0,0,0)`. The plane with the texture is in the same position. So try to put some distance between your camera and the plane along z-axis. For example, `camera.position.set(0,0,img.width)`.

Comment: Still nothing, but I tought about that as well and tried moving the camera and/or the plane without any effect.

Comment: Maybe you call `RunWebGL(...)` before an image was loaded into `img` or drawn on `canvas`.

Comment: Good Idea, I just tested it by using a setTimeout function but unfortunately it's still not displaying anyhting...

Comment: Could you provide more code? For example, how you set variables `img` and `canvas`. Can you create a jsfiddle example?

Comment: I just updated my post. Regards, Michael

Comment: You have a spelling error: "var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(img.widht,"  It should be "image.width".  I don't know if that is the only problem (your jsfiddle simply displays an image, you need to add all the three.js/javascript which you are trying to debug).